# Issues opening public ip on browser for flask app EC2 instance

Tags: flask, amazon-ec2

I am trying to run an flask app on AWS EC2 env for the first time and I am STRUGGLING.
I have set up a python virtual env.
EC2 security group configurations inbound:
[image]

Here is outbound:
[image]

Below is the code to my flask app:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

then on terminal I run `python3 app.py`
and I see the output:

```
 * Serving Flask app 'app'
 * Debug mode: off
WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
```

I ran `ufw status` and I see `Status: inactive`
When I try opening on my public IP address: `https://18.XXX.XXX.XX`
I see nothing. Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Your Flask app is running on port 5000, and further, bound to `127.0.0.1`, so it will only be accessible on the instance via port 5000.  Add `host='0.0.0.0'` to the Flask run line if you want to open it to other callers, but don't ignore the "Do not use it in a production deployment" warning.